# Grails logging from grails-app/utils

Tags: grails, logging

I would like to log from utils classes in grails-app/utils folder.

Does anyone know what package should I put in Config.groovy log section ? I tried my own package "com.company" and "grails.utils" but no one works.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `log` field is added to all Groovy classes - this happens during compilation via an AST transform. If logging doesn't appear to be working, add `println log.name` in a method that gets executed and you'll see the whole logger name to use in `Config.groovy` in the console.

As @dmahapatro mentioned, `grails-app/utils` is not for utility classes. In early versions of Grails the folder was added with the expectation that it would contain various artifact types that didn't merit their own `grails-app` subfolder. No other artifacts beyond codecs were added though, so codecs are the only classes that should be there. Utility classes should always go in `src/groovy` or `src/java` - only artifact classes and config files belong under `grails-app`.

Comment: The log is working because I can log in error but not in debug (root logger is info and I try to debug only classes in grails-app/utils)

Comment: If it's not a codec, move it from `grails-app/utils` to `src/groovy` and file the logging problem from there.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `info` level logging is required, you can use:

```
//if logging required for all classes under grails-app/utils
info 'grails.app.utils' 

//if logging required for a particular class under grails-app/utils
info 'grails.app.utils.com.company.SampleUtil'
```

Also remember that `grails-app/utils` is mainly dedicated for [codecs](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.x/guide/single.html#codecs) and not for utility classes. In case you are looking to add utility classes for the app then it should go under `src/groovy` or `src/java` respectively for groovy or java classes.

Comment: debug 'grails.app.utils' does not work :(
However, I will move all classes from grails-app/utils to src/groovy because this is actually not codec but marshallers. Thanks for the reply